# Setting the value to list

Tags: java

I am facing a issue in setting the value to the list of SoyFileSupplier,the list should have a value of type file,the soyfilesetParse class is used for parsing by passing a soyFileSupplier list,setting the value to a file.(sample.soy)

```
The sample code is as below:

public class test {
     main() {
          soyTree=parseSoyFiles(soyFileSuppliers);
     }
}
```

The calling class is :

```
public class soyFileSetParse {
    public static SoyFileSetNode parseSoyFiles(List<SoyFileSupplier> soyFileSuppliers)
        throws SoySyntaxException {

        IdGenerator nodeIdGen = new IntegerIdGenerator();
        SoyFileSetNode soyTree = new SoyFileSetNode(nodeIdGen.genStringId(), nodeIdGen);

        for (SoyFileSupplier soyFileSupplier : soyFileSuppliers) {
            soyTree.addChild(parseSoyFileHelper(soyFileSupplier, nodeIdGen));
        }

        return soyTree;
    }
}
```

Setting to file type :

```
public class SoyFileSupplier {
  /**
   * Creates a new {@code SoyFileSupplier} given a {@code File}.
   *
   * @param inputFile The Soy file.
   */
  public SoyFileSupplier(File inputFile) {
      this(Files.newReaderSupplier(inputFile, Charsets.UTF_8), inputFile.getPath());
  }
```

I am not getting what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since `parseSoyFiles(...)` is a `static` method of the `soyFileSetParse` class, you'll need to invoke it with the class name, without the need for creating an instance of the class, as in

```
ClassName.methodName(args)
```

Therefore, the content of your `main()` method should look as follows

```
SoyFileSetNode soyTree = soyFileSetParse.parseSoyFiles(soyFileSuppliers);
```

Comment: And also use `public static void main(String[] args)` for the main method. And also initialize _soyfileSuppliers_ `SoyFileSupplier soyFileSuppliers = new SoyFileSupplier(new File("path/to/file"));`. Not to mention following java case conventions.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, Yes - there are many things wrong with the code snippet. :/